# Why are my replys looping instead of whole program

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone help me troubleshoot my code the reply from going through the code at the end just loops instead of begining the program again completely would be brilliant is someone could help me thanks and i know its very basic and maybe not the best way to do it but as long as it works its fine.

```
start = input("Do you want to make an order? ")
while start == "Y" or start == "y" :
    title = input("Enter book title: ")
    sPrice = float(input("Enter price of book: "))
    voucher = input("Do you have a voucher? ")    
    while sPrice >0 :
        amount = float(input("Enter amount of books: "))
        while amount >= 1 and amount <= 80 :
            if amount >= 5 and amount <= 10 :
                disc = 5
            elif amount >= 11 and amount <= 50 :
                disc = 7.5
            elif amount >= 51 and amount <= 80 :
                disc = 10
            else :
                disc = 0
            base = sPrice * amount
            discVal = (base * disc) / 100
            dPrice = base - discVal


            if voucher == "Y" or voucher == "y" and dPrice >= 25 :
                voucherValue = 25
            else :
                voucherValue = 0
            fPrice = dPrice - voucherValue
            print (f"Discount rate: {disc}%")
            print (f"Discount value: £{discVal:.2f}")
            print (f"Total before discount: £{base:.2f}")
            print (f"Total after discount: £{dPrice:.2f}")
            if voucher == "Y" or voucher == "y" and dPrice >= 25 :
                print (f"Value of voucher: £{voucherValue:.2f}")
            print (f"Final cost of order: £{fPrice:.2f}")
        else :
            print ("ERROR - Invalid amount!")
            amount = float(input("Enter amount of books: "))
    else :
        print ("ERROR - Price too low!")
        sPrice = float(input("Enter price of book: "))
else :
    start = input("Do you want to make an order? ")
```

Comment: I assume this is for school, have you learned about functions yet?

Comment: You need to include `if` at two place just to validate the input value. Change `while sPrice >0 :` to `if sPrice >0 :` and line `while amount >= 1 and amount <= 80 :` to `if amount >= 1 and amount <= 80 :`

Comment: @chrisHG yeah its for school but we dont learn about functions until next block

Comment: @Ratnesh ill try that thanks

Comment: @Ratnesh i think thats it fixed now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `if` at two place just to validate the input value.

Change `while sPrice >0 :` to `if sPrice >0 :` and line `while amount >= 1 and amount <= 80 :` to `if amount >= 1 and amount <= 80 :`